# Does Svelte do away with MVC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svelte

I just got introduced to Svelte. And my first impressions were that Svelte seems to place styling and functionality related code all together in one place. If that's true doesn't it do away with the age-old MVC concept?

For example, this is what would happen in Svelte.

```
<script>
  import TodoHeader from "./TodoHeader.svelte";
  import TodoList from "./TodoList.svelte";
  import { itemStore } from "./store";
</script>

<style>
  main {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<main>
  <div>Total item: {$itemStore.length}</div>
  <TodoHeader />
  <TodoList />
</main>
```

Seeing `<html>` code with `<script>` and `<style>` code, all in one, gave me the heebie-jeebies! Is this all true?

Comment: In React: seeing <html> code in javascript file, all in one, gave me the heebie-jeebies! ;)

Comment: MVC doesn't make sense and is deeply flawed, but "styling" and "functionality" and "code" are all part of the view concern.

Comment: If you're using Vue you'd probably be seeing <html> code with <script> and <style> code all in one too :)

Comment: @AndyRay Oh really!? That's an interesting perspective. Would you care to elaborate... Or perhaps, point me towards something that will? Thanks.

Comment: If you would use Aurelia, you would see html, css, javascript code all in separated files - enjoy ;)

Comment: The separation of concerns in MVC does not mean separating "files". If you want seperate files you can still do that (in Vue for instance) .

Comment: It would be more correct to say that MVC "as it is commonly understood" is deeply flawed. The original MVC concept is quite flexible and is compatible with having encapsulated components, or not, as long as there is some separation of concerns going on in your app between the Model and the presentation of it. (And original MVC doesn't even mandate use of the observer pattern.) See this link for more info, especially the "MVC Pattern Language" PDF: https://folk.universitetetioslo.no/trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is known as an Encapsulated Component, and is a core concept of Svelte, along with most modern frontend frameworks.

It is understandable to find this odd at first, especially having been ingrained with the notion that this is "bad" for so long, in web development.

However, you must understand that encapsulating your components makes your application much easier to reason about and develop, and makes reusing your components significantly easier, both within the same app and across different apps.

An added benefit of Svelte is that it scopes your styles within a component, so none of the styles you define in Component A will affect anything outside of it, which makes understanding your CSS structure a lot easier.

Note that Svelte is largely un-opinionated, these concepts are the defaults, but it will allow you to use Svelte however you like - nothing stops you having global styles, centralised logic, or anything else.